# To prove if and only if a function involving sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Consider $f: A\rightarrow B$. Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if $X = f^{-1}(f(X))$ for all $X\subseteq A$. Prove that $f$ is surjective if and only if $f(f^{-1}(Y)) = Y$ for all $Y\subseteq B$.

So I am having troubles with proving surjectivity. I understand that I must do this in two parts: prove that $f$ is surjective $\Rightarrow$ $X = f^{-1}(f(X))$ and $X = f^{-1}(f(X)) \Rightarrow$ $f$ is surjective.

But apart from this, I really dont have any idea where to start.

Comment: Recall that $X = f^{-1}(f(X))$ means that $X \subset f^{-1}(f(X))$ and $f^{-1}(f(X))\subset X$

Comment: If f is not surjective there is a y in Y so that no x in A has f (x)=y. So  y can not be in f (f'(Y)). If f is surjective for any y in y there is an x in A so that f (x)=y. So x in f'(Y). So $f (x)=y\in f (f'(Y)) $. So $Y\subset f (f'(Y))$.

Comment: You mixed up. The necessary and sufficient condition for surjectivity is okay in your first paragraph, but wrong in your second (there it is interchanged with the necessary and sufficient condition for injectivity).

Answer (score 0):

If Y = f(X), then $Y = Y \cap f(X) = ff^{-1}(Y).$
If $Y = ff^{-1}(Y),$ then $Y = Y \cap f(X) \subseteq f(X).$